# Excel - retrieving cell values from a group of cells

Tags: excel, formulas

I have 2 blocks of information. One block has sizing across the top row, and store and styles down the left column.

I have to enter this information into a data system in one column by store/style/size.

I've combined data in the first block to match the values of conctanated values from second block, but I cannot figure out which formula to use to "find" the values to populate data.

Can someone help??

Comment: It might be helpful if you posted a small screenshot example of your data and also your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you mean your "second block" (or data range) has more data than your "first block" (data range), both data ranges have a common identifier (store+style+size), which you want to use to pull in data from your 2nd data range to your 1st data range.

If so, then a simple `VLOOOKUP` will help...

```
=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,[range_lookup])
```

Where...

`lookup_value` is your identifier

`table_array` is the cell range of your "second block" (note the `lookup_value` field should always appear to the far left of this range

`col_index_num` the number columns to offset from the `lookup_value` field for the value you want returned

`[range_lookup]` best just to enter the value `FALSE` here.  That just means it will look for an exact match

while your entering your formula, press `F1` to get further help on `VLOOKUP`'s